# Using weak references with structs with lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, lifetime, weak-references, reference-counting

I want to implement the observer pattern using [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) smart pointers. Ideally this would look something like the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e0e4afc644af49decbd025f94b9353b)):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Observable {
    observers: Vec<Weak<Observer>>,
}

impl Observable {
    fn new() -> RefCell<Observable> {
        RefCell::new(Self {
            observers: Vec::new(),
        })
    }
}

struct Observer<'a> {
    parent: &'a RefCell<Observable>,
}


fn observe(observable: &RefCell<Observable>) -> Rc<Observer> {
    let observer = Observer {
        parent: observable,
    };
    let observer = Rc::new(observer);
    observable.borrow_mut().observers.push(Rc::downgrade(&observer));
    observer
}


fn main() {
    let mut observable = Observable::new();
    let observer = observe(&observable);
}
```

This fails however, because no lifetime parameter is provided for the `Observer` type in the `observers` field of `Observable`:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:5:25
  |
5 |     observers: Vec<Weak<Observer>>,
  |                         ^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
4 ~ struct Observable<'a> {
5 ~     observers: Vec<Weak<Observer<'a>>>,
  |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0106`.
```

Is there a way in which this lifetime can be added to the `observers` field or removed from the `Observer` without causing issues with cyclic lifetime dependencies? Is there some way in which the `Weak`ness of the pointer can apply to the lifetime of the `Observer` itself, as well as the lifetime of the reference?

Comment: If there isn't a logical lifetime for the parent RefCell, I think you should have a `Rc<RefCell<...>>` instead of `&RefCell<...>`. In that way the struct field is owned and doesn't need a lifetime.

Comment: This does solve the syntactical issue but also changes the working of the program quite a lot. It means that an `Observer` can keep an `Observable` alive. In my real-world case, it makes more sense that this is checked at compile time using standard references than with run-time reference counting.

Comment: I see now I had misread your question, sorry. It looks like you might be looking for a self lifetime parameter, where the `Observer`s' lifetimes would equal what they observe, but if I remember correctly that's not yet possible in Rust.

Comment: I think this is somewhat of an answer: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-connect-global-static-variables-to-lifetimed-objects/61612 although to be honest this goes over my head.